# SharePoint 2013 List Font too large

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I recently upgraded from 2010 to 2013 on premises.  A standard contact list now shows in a large font (items and everything) that takes too much space on the page.  Was fine before.  Any ideas?  See picture.[image]

Comment: Do you have any custom css attached to your SharePoint

Answer (score 1):

Few things for you to try:

1) If your site is not using the default (seattle) master page, set it as that to see if the issue goes away.

2) Edit the page, remove the list web part from the page.  Save the page.  Then edit it again and add it back.

3) Disable your Skype browser plugin.

Answer (score 0):

check the css attached with the masterpage!

to find the culprit css and class/id use F12 developer tools to inspect an element that doesnt look right!

when in f12 developer you should see to the righ when you click on a given control the id or class of the control with its css thats attached to it, it will also show you the css file name that it comes from!